# PHP: Trying to get property or methods of non-object

Tags: php

I am trying to save an object as property in an another class, PHP throwing notices and fatal errors. Simplified version of my code:

```
<?php
    class A {
        public function a() {
            // do something
        }
    }
    $A = new A();

    class B {
        private $A;
        public function __constructor($A) {
            $this->A = $A;
        }
        private function b() {
            if($this->A->a()) { // This line is referred by PHP
                // do something
            }
        }
    }

    $B = new B($A);
```

Comment: What notices and fatal errors are thrown? You never ever call method b() of class B. So you should not get an error in that line. You say you use a simplified version of your code. Does the error happen with the simplified version?

Comment: @Seb Problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Change `__constructor` to `__construct` and PHP will process your code correctly.  Constructors in PHP are always named `__construct`.  See [**the documentation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I saw that I had written `constructor` instead of `construct` :D

Comment: :) If this fixes your problem, please remember to accept it as the answer!

Comment: I know but it asked me to wait for 10 minutes and I had to go at that time, sorry. I have accepted the answer now.